# Async function to shuffle array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got the below code from StackOverflow for shuffling an array and it's working fine.Can you help me to convert this as an async function?

```
const src = [...'abcdefg'];

const shuffle = arr => 
  [...arr].reduceRight((res,_,__,s) => 
    (res.push(s.splice(0|Math.random()*s.length,1)[0]), res),[]);

console.log(shuffle(src));
```

Comment: Could you tell why you want it to be async? There’s nothing that could be done asynchronously there

Comment: What do you mean by converting to async?! adding an `async` keyword before that makes it async (it returns a promise)! but there is no benefit to that. why do you want this?

Comment: What have you tried on your own already? SO isn't a code writing service. Is there some issue you believe making this function asynchronous will help resolve? Possible [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const shuffle = async (arr) => 
  [...arr].reduceRight((res, _, __, s) =>
    (res.push(s.splice(0 | Math.random() * s.length, 1)[0]), res), []);



async function shuffle (arr) {
  return [...arr].reduceRight((res, _, __, s) =>
    (res.push(s.splice(0 | Math.random() * s.length, 1)[0]), res), []);
}
```

Comment: Your first function doesn't return anything because you wrapped the arrow function in curly braces which cancels the implicit return. You can wrap it in normal parentheses if you'd like, or add the `return` keyword